# Отрисовка выбранного radio батона

Tags: php

Например, в массиве есть ключ answer, со значением 2 и надо сделать, что бы появилась форма, с радиокнопками и автоматически, была нажата вторая.

Я это сделал, но у меня код очень большой, как можно его сократить?

```
    <?php
if($question['answer'] == 1) {
     echo '
       <label>1. <input name="answer" checked type="radio" value="1"></label>
       <label>2. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="2"></label>
       <label>3. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="3"></label>
       <label>4. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="4"></label>
        ';
}

if($question['answer'] == 2) {
     echo '
       <label>1. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="1"></label>
       <label>2. <input name="answer" checked type="radio" value="2"></label>
       <label>3. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="3"></label>
       <label>4. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="4"></label>
        ';
}

if($question['answer'] == 3) {
     echo '
       <label>1. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="1"></label>
       <label>2. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="2"></label>
       <label>3. <input name="answer" checked type="radio" value="3"></label>
       <label>4. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="4"></label>
        ';
}

if($question['answer'] == 4) {
     echo '
       <label>1. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="1"></label>
       <label>2. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="2"></label>
       <label>3. <input name="answer" type="radio" value="3"></label>
       <label>4. <input name="answer" checked type="radio" value="4"></label>
        ';
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так:

```
function answers_echo($checked = 1, $count = 4)
{
    for( $i = 1; $i<=$count; $i++ )
    {
        $string = '<label>'.$i.'<input name="answer" ';
        if( $i == $checked )
        {
            $string .='checked ';
        }
        $string .= 'type="radio" value="'.$i.'"></label>';
        echo $string;
    }
}
```

т.е передаем значения лейбла, который должен быть отмечен и их количество. И кстати тут прям идеально использовать switch case

```
switch($question['answer'])
{
  case 1:
     answers_echo(1);
     break;
  case 2:
     answers_echo(2);
     break;
  case 3:
     answers_echo(3);
     break;
  case 4:
     answers_echo(4);
     break;
}
```

Хотя можно и так:

```
answers_echo($question['answer']);
```

P.S. Я бы посоветовал на досуге посмотреть что такое шаблонизаторы и для чего они нужны, т.к. выводить таким образом html не комильфо.

Comment: Спасибо за решение.